# String Regex Help C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that reads a string, and if the last character is something like !"£$% etc, it ignores the last character, reads the string (to allow my code to look it up in a dictionary class) and then outputs the string, with the character on the end it ignored. Is this actually possible, or do I have to just remove the last character?

So far...

```
foreach(var line in yourReader)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>(); // your replacement dictionaries
    foreach(var kvp in dict)
    {
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(line,"(\s|,|\.|:|\\t)" + kvp.Key + "(\s|,|\.|:|\\t)","\0" + kvp.Value + "\1");
    }
}
```

I've also been told to try this

```
var trans = textbox1.Text;

foreach (var kvp in d) //d is my dictionary so use yours
{
     trans = trans.Replace(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}

textbox2.Text = trans;
```

but have literally no idea what it does

Comment: Please edit your question to add details. Don't to that in comments.

Comment: I recommend using this handy cheat sheet of reg ex expressions: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find any point using Regex, so I hope this will help:

```
        const int ARRAY_OFFSET = 1;

        List<char> ForbiddenChars = new List<char>()
        {
            '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '£' //Add more if you'd like
        };

        string myString = "Hello World!&";

        foreach (var forbiddenChar in ForbiddenChars)
        {
            if (myString[myString.Length - ARRAY_OFFSET] == forbiddenChar)
            {
                myString = myString.Remove(myString.Length - ARRAY_OFFSET);
                break;
            }
        }
```

**Edit:**

I checked the old code, and it had a problem: when the string's last "forbidden" characters were in order of the `ForbiddenChars` array it deleted all of them. if your string was "Hello World&!" it would delete both the ! and &. so I set a `break;` and it won't be a problem anymore.

Comment: perfect! thanks for pushing me in the right direction. i need to add whatever the forbidden character is to a variable to i can add it on again at the end, but i know how to do it now, so thanks!

Comment: @JordanMoffat My pleasure. I did have to fix my answer so please check the edit. all it needed was to add a "break;" once the `if` occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx). A regular expression such as `[!"£$%]$` should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I'd recommend using the regex expression for a range of characters to remove the !"£$% etc.

The way you'd want to use this in your case would be something like:

```
"<the bit you want to capture>(?:[!-%]\\r)"
```

The `(?:[!-%]\\r)` bit matches, but doesn't store, a single character in range !-% which comes right before a carriage return character.

I also recommend using this handy cheat sheet of reg ex expressions:

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet